# Get NavController from fragment context to launch SimpleDialog with callback listener

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app with one activity and many fragments. Basic structure is default and created by Android Studio with `NavHostFragment`. As it's recommended to use DialogFragment for dialogs I created simple dialog and added it to navigation xml file by a standard way

```
<dialog
    android:id="@+id/simple_dialog"
    android:name="com.lumisdinos.tabletransform.ui.dialog.SimpleDialog"
    android:label="SimpleDialog" >
</dialog>
```

SimpleDialog file

```
class SimpleDialog : DialogFragment() {

internal lateinit var listener: SimpleDialogListener


override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    try {
        listener = context as SimpleDialogListener
    } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
        // My activity doesn't implement the interface and throw this exception
        throw ClassCastException(
            (context.toString() +
                    " must implement SimpleDialogListener")
        )
    }
}

interface SimpleDialogListener {
    fun onPositiveClick()
    fun onNegativeClick()
    fun onNeutralClick()
}
...
```

which I intended to launch from fragments like this

```
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString...
val navController = requireActivity().findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
navController.navigate(R.id.simple_dialog, bundle)
```

Listener is implemented in fragment which the dialog is launched from

```
open class FileFragment : DaggerFragment(), SimpleDialog.SimpleDialogListener {
override fun onPositiveClick() {}
override fun onNegativeClick(){}
override fun onNeutralClick(){}
...
```

So here I am getting `ClassCastException` because I get

```
val navController = requireActivity()...
```

with help of activity, not fragment, and when I implement the listener in activity all works fine.

My question is: how to get navController from fragment using the structure above?

Comment: I'm stuck on this too, were you able to solve it?

Comment: @Steve no, I did it another way, I simply created AlertDialog and passed there all what I need, it works good, and only reason why I wanted to use DialogFragment is that it is recommended by Google